# Weird OleDbDataAdapter Fill behavior (hangs with explicit fields) on IBM i System

Tags: db2, odbc, oledb

we're migrating our *IBM i System* from OS 6.0 to 7.4; we're testing all the applications which somehow connect and read/write data to it and we found a weird behavior in one of them.

The application is simply trying to fill a DataTable via OleDbDataAdapter:

```
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
Dim dt As New DataTable
[...]
da.Fill(dt)
```

The query is a simple select similar to this:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table WHERE field1=something AND field2=something
```

.. and it returns 99% of the times (if not 100%) always an empty resultset (0 rows).

**Problem is**: the command *da.Fill(dt)* hangs for minutes most of the time with no specific reason or errors.

**What's weird**? If I replace the list of fields with *:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1=something AND field2=something
```

It works ALWAYS with no delays or glitches.

We really got no clues: could this be related to the new OS/400 version (7.4 instead of 6.0)? Maybe we need an updated ODBC driver (we're using a very old one)?
I cannot say where the command is hanging (ODBC side? IBM side? ...), but on *IBM i System* everything seems just to be in idle..

Thanks!

--

I did other tests changing the query a bit, and this are the results:

```
's = "Select SNORAF, SRIAFF, SCDREG, SCDPRV, SCDCOM, SCDTIP, SCDTIQ, SPSC01 from             'KO
's = "Select SNORAF, SRIAFF, SCDREG, SCDPRV, SCDCOM, SCDTIP, SPSC01, SCDTIQ from             'KO
's = "Select SNORAF, SRIAFF, SCDREG, SCDPRV, SCDCOM, SCDTIP, SCDTIQ, SPSC01, SCDTIQ from     'OK
's = "Select SNORAF, SRIAFF, SCDREG, SCDPRV, SCDCOM, SCDTIP, SCDTIQ, SCDTIQ, SCDTIQ from     'OK
's = "Select SNORAF, SRIAFF, SCDREG, SCDPRV, SCDCOM, SCDTIP, SPSC01 from                     'OK
's = "Select * from                                                                          'OK
's = "Select SPSC01                                                                          'OK
```

On the right, the results: the first two queries didn't work, all the other ones work fine.

Comment: Post original SQL. Problem might be with column names

Comment: You're right, that's why I did other tests; the queries and the outcomes are in the original post. Thanks!